# Modifying json file via Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, frontend

I am new to Javascript and have already programmed a system where I can search up and filter the users in my data.json file. But how can I build an application that can add users to the data.json file. Thank you for your help,
Benjamin

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="name" placeholder="name">
        <input class="email" placeholder="email">
        <button class="submit">Add User</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Leanne Gr",
      "email": "Sincere@april.biz"
  }
]
```

Comment: Storing data in a file (or, probably more ideally, a database) would be something for server-side code.  A browser can't write to a file on the server.

Comment: This is often done by building a server-side app (which you can build in JavaScript, PHP, C#, etc.) that performs CRUD operations on a database. Your choice of language will influence your database options. You should also familiarize yourself with the concept of MVC, which is a design pattern for keeping display and data separate to allow changes in each area without affecting the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the npm package

> browserify-fs

to do that.
When you installed the package you can use the fileSystem.writeFile() function:

```js
const fileSystem = require("browserify-fs")

const client = {
 "Name": "John Doe",
 "Mail": "mail@gmail.com"
}
const data = JSON.stringify(client)

fileSystem.writeFile("./data.json", data, err=>{
 if(err){
   console.log("Error writing file" ,err)
 } else {
   console.log('JSON data is written to the file successfully')
 }
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but when I put in a function and run it, it won't work and I looked into the console which said " require is not defined". I don't now how to fix it because I won't understand how to define it.

Comment: Did you install the package? (npm install browserify-fs) Are you familiar with npm workflow?

Answer (score -1):

You Can do this with [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) requests. But you need a server to host your json.

You can host a local server using `json-server` npm package to host your own JSON server

In conclusion you need a server and `XMLHttpRequest` to edit using `Javascript`

Other wise you need a **Server Side** program language like `PHP`

Note that `Javascript` **Client Side** programming Language